# How to pass parameters to Backbone collection along with reset

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to pass parameters as well as use {reset:true} when i do a fetch.

How can i accomplish both ?

Code

```
App.Collections.Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({

   model : App.Models.ItemInfo,
   url : "api/category/category123/city"

});

var itemCollection = new App.Collections.Items();
itemCollection.fetch({reset : true});

http://127.0.0.1/api/category/city?p=1&ps=4
```

How can I pass in p=1 and p=4 as the paremeters along with reset ?

Comment: Why are you passing in `reset` to a new Collection instance ? That doesn't seem to make much sense ? Usually you call reset when you want to update or `reset` an entire collection

Comment: yes but for some reason it's not fetching unless I pass reset.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var itemCollection = new App.Collections.Items();
itemCollection.fetch({data: {p: 1, ps: 4 }});
```

Comment: You don't need reset, fetch will do the initial data fetch. If you want to reset after that just call reset again. Reset won't fetch any data until you call fetch again.

Comment: willem my initial data fetch without reset doesn't fetch data. I read that newer backbone version forces user to pass reset as well even for first reset.

Comment: What version of backbone are you using ?

Comment: backbone version is 1.1.0

Comment: @user1184100: You'd pass `{reset: true, data: { p: 1, ps: 4}}` if you wanted the collection to use `reset` (and trigger a `"reset"` event) instead of `set` (which triggers, `"add"`, `"remove"`, and `"change"` events) to update the collection with the new models. BTW, this is documented: ["**jQuery.ajax** options can also be passed directly as fetch options, so to fetch a specific page of a paginated collection: `Documents.fetch({data: {page: 3}})`"](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch).